# Passing javascript variable into PHP and making mysql query

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I've the following script (taken from a large script) saved as example3.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var layer;

//where layer is a table like 
------------------------------------
BUSNAME       +    Category    +
------------------------------------
200 Bay       +   Restaurant   +
201 Bay       +   Bank         +
202 Bay       +   School       +
203 Bay       +   Restaurant   +
204 Bay       +   School       +
205 Bay       +   Restaurant   +
206 Bay       +   Restaurant   +
207 Bay       +   School       +
208 Bay       +   Restaurant   +
209 Bay       +   Restaurant   +
------------------------------------

window.location.href = "example3.php?layer="+ layer;

<?php
  //Make a MySQL Connection
  $query = "SELECT Category, COUNT(BUSNAME) 
    FROM ".$_GET['layer']." GROUP BY Category"; 
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  //Print out result
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "There are ".$row['COUNT(BUSNAME)']. " " .$row['Category']. "items.";
  echo "<br/>";
  }
?>

</script>
```

Don't no why it is not working. Any suggestion must be appreciated.

Comment: [SQL injection alert!](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

Comment: assign a value to the layer variable..

Comment: @teresko and David, come on, don't just point it out, tell the man how to fix it!

Answer (score 4):

if you have dynamical table name, **your database design is wrong**

as for your script, it just makes no sense.

make in in 2 parts: JS page and PHP page. and call this PHP page with window.location.href

Answer (score 1):

I suggest JSON-encoding the table on the client side (in JS). Use POST to send it, then decode it on the server side (in PHP).

Most popular JS libraries do have JSON-encoding functions, the PHP function is called [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Answer (score 0):

As Balus pointed out, watch out for SQL Injection. When you reach the php page, does the `$_GET['layer']` equals something?

Does your javascript variable equals something?
`var layer = "layer`

"layer" being the actual name for the table inside of your database.

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT**

In this context `mysql_real_escape_string()` does not work.

```
$layer = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['layer']);
$query = "SELECT Category, COUNT(BUSNAME) 
FROM `".$layer."` GROUP BY Category"; <<-- this doesn't work.
```

Because mysql_real_escape_string does not escape backticks `

**With values it does work**

You need to run each and every **value** you get with `$_GET` though mysql_real_escape_string(). *(or use PDO's)*
On top of that every value that you put into a query you need to enclose with single quotes `'`.

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['fieldname']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE f1 = '".$value."'"; <<-- this works
                                        ^          ^
```

Links:
SQL-injection attack: [How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain)
PDO's: [mysqli or PDO - what are the pros and cons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons)

Will update as soon as I find a fix your your particular SQL-injection problem.

Comment: did you happen to use PDO yourself?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not a php man. I'm a delphi programmer, Delphi is strongly typed, so inserting integers I sometimes do as `query1.SQL.text:= 'SELECT a FROM b WHERE a = '+IntToStr(i);`. If I put strings in I always do `query1.ParamByName('x').AsString:= MyString;`

Comment: Comment is: - unhelpful - rude - incorrect - incomplete to name a few.

Comment: @Col and besides I'm answering the MySQL part, with a light sprinkling of php to glue things together. But if the post has factual errors, feel free to edit them out.

Comment: yeah. flagged the answer for it's extremely poor quality. should've been do it instead of commenting. apologies.

Comment: OK, that's cool, but what exactly **is** wrong with using `mysql_real_escape_string()` to prevent SQL-injection attacks?

Comment: @Pekka, thank you, @Col. Scrapnel I know you get upset at the poor quality of the php answers. Will edit the answer as soon as I find a way to fix the SQL-injection.

Comment: I made the comment [an answer to your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5811834/why-would-this-be-poor-php-code/5811853#5811853). @Johan the only reliable way I know, as said, is to check against a list of known valid values (like from a `SHOW TABLES` command).

Comment: @Pekka, thank you thought it was important to know, because I can't be the only one to make this beginners error.